# When to use Groups in Regular Expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm a newbie and learning more about regular expressions. I'm still unclear as to why we use groups. I used them in the below regular expression below:

```
(http:)\//(\w)+\.(\w)+\.(\w)+
```

This will extract URL's, as in the below sentence:

```
This is http://www.google.com, this is http://www.yahoo.com.
```

I did use groups but I was very unsure as to why. I saw this explanation online but confused as to what it means:

By placing part of a regular expression inside round brackets or parentheses, you can group that part of the regular expression together. This allows you to apply a quantifier to the entire group or to restrict alternation to part of the regex.

So any simplified clarification of groups would be great.

Comment: Usually to capture subparts (i.e. protocol, domain, path, querystring, etc.)

Comment: It allows you to use part of the matched values as a unit, for instance for repetition or replacement. In the particular regex you've posted, it's used (as @WillemVanOnsem said), to capture the individual subparts of the URL.

Comment: tl;dr: for your current purposes you don't need them, and you will know when you do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I use groups it is usually because I need to replace some, but not all, of a specific regular expression pattern.

As an example let's say you have a large text file, and you want to change all hostnames that end in `.com` to end in `.biz` instead.

Obviously you can't just blindly replace `.com` with `.biz`, because that text could occur somewhere that isn't a hostname.  So you need a way to identify just pieces of text that look like hostnames.

I won't go into the full hostname rules here, but for purposes of this example, let's pretend that hostnames are two to four sequences of alphabetic characters separated by periods, such as `ibm.com` or `www.santa.northpole.org`.

A regular expression to identify hostnames that end in `.com` might look like this:

```
([a-z]+\.){1,3}com
```

Which means "one or more letters followed by a period, occurring one to three times, followed by `com`."

The first part of the expression is inside parentheses, meaning it can be handled separately from the rest.  So you could have a replacement pattern like this:

```
\1.biz
```

Meaning "Keep the first group expression unchanged and put `.biz` at the end."